# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/Property.class

Tags: android, linkedin-api, android-support-library

I am new in the Android Development. We have requirement to share content using Linked In with Android. I implemented the code given in the link "https://github.com/mukesh4u/Android-LinkedIn-Demo". I also added the module dependencies for the project in Android studio. I am able to clean and build the project successfully but fail while running on Android mobile device. I also created the Sample app using the link "https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps" .

Also i make the changes in **LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET** parameters that are required during Linked In integration in the code.

I also set JDK Version under **File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings-> Java Compiler as a 1.6.**

I am getting the below exception while running the app in mobile device.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

**What went wrong:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/Property.class
```

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }    
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.jar')
}
```

I would be **thankful** if anyone have solution about the same.

Regards,
Datta.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.activity"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }   
}

Comment: Continue build.gradle due to text area size issue.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')

Comment: compile files('libs/trang.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
}

Comment: added build.gradle

Comment: remove one `compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar') `

Comment: Even if I removed "httpclient-4.3.3.jar" i wont be able to share the content using "DefaultHttpClient" class. So i used "httpclient-4.0.jar"  still i get  exception "java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/code/linkedinapi/schema/Property.class" .  Our requirement is to share content using Linked In in Android.

Comment: did you using latest version of linkdln https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk ??

Comment: Yes, I am using li-android-sdk-1.1.4-release sdk "Mobile SDK for Android"

Comment: call `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" ` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'`

Comment: same problem for that ? inform .

Comment: i removed android.support.v4.jar file and its working warning shows on Gradle Console in Android Studio like 1)  android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'actionIntent' dynamically 2) android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically 3) android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'icon' dynamically 4)  twitter4j.internal.logging.Logger accesses a method 'dumpConfiguration()' dynamically.

Comment: 5) You should consider keeping the signature attributes (using '-keepattributes Signature').(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual toubleshooting.html#attributes) . 6)  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass) 7) You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or their implementations (using '-keep').(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)

Comment: Honestly speaking , Don't know

Comment: 8)(using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember) .It would be thankful if you know the solution for the same.

Comment: for better . Please add your `build.gradle` in question section